# I want to get message list from table in notification symbol drop down

Tags: php, yii

Here I have a notification symbol with unread message count, I want to display message list with drop down, I want to fire `ajax` with functionality, like when I click on message then the message circle will change unfill from fill table name is notification with `id`, `message`, `url` field

```
       <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="orange-count">
                <?php echo Storenotification::model()->count("store_id='.Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . "' AND IFNULL(readdate,'')='' "); 
               ?>                                                   
          </div>
         <i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-2x">
            </i>
         </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu notification-content pull-right">
         <ul class="list-unstyled">   
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="pull-right" onclick="readdone()">
          <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
               </a> 
           </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

here I want message (message is field) list from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `setData()` function to display string into ckeditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.description.setData(values.description);
```

Let me know if you face any further query/concern regarding the same.